# Including a header file in ESP IDF compiler

Tags: c, esp32, esp-idf

Im trying to run an example project from esp who, it is under single chip examples, cloned from https://github.com/espressif/esp-who.

Its recognition example. Im including a esp_http_client.h but it cant find it.

There is a CMkakeLists.txt and Makefile.
My first question is, do I have to edit the one of those files to include the header, or I have to add the directory path in the gcc.
If so how do I do that.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify non-default components as a requirement, in your case `esp_http_client`. Default components are added by IDF automatically, a list can be found here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html?highlight=default%20component#common-component-requirements

If you can, please use cmake. An explanation how to add a component can be found here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html?highlight=default%20component#component-requirements.

Another easy way would be to look at the esp_http_client example. I uses a "common" component for all idf examples which might be enough for starting: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/esp_http_client.

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, first had wrong links in the answer! I corrected them.